# Google Cloud with MySQL and Cloud SQL and phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, google-cloud-storage

I recently registered to Google Cloud for PHP hosting. I just created an instance and installed apache, PHP, MySQL from CLI from instance. Everything is working fine but have some confusion regarding to phpMyAdmin and MySQL database.

In below tutorial

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine

they say to create Google Cloud SQL. But I already installed MySQL from CLI so it is also required to create Cloud SQL and put SQL instance id in installing phpMyAdmin.

If yes I am also trying this but the following command is not working

appcfg.py update .

also bz2 is not extract so I am do from .zip file and what is yaml file? Why it is needed? sorry for some stupid question.

Comment: facing same issue...!